# How does this expect statement work in TCL?

Tags: tcl, expect

I read the following code, but I do not understand how it works:

```
set accum ""
set timeout 1
    expect {
        -re {.+} {
            set accum "${accum}$expect_out(0,string)" 
            exp_continue
        }
    }
set timeout 10
```

at the beginning, we set accum and timeout, then there is a expect command try to match something? and after it, we set the timeout as 10, how the whole code works? and does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the code times out (1 second *after the last match of anything*), any time it matches something (which is any sequence of characters — possibly excluding newline — because of `-re {.+}`) it appends it to the `accum` variable and restarts expecting something (the `exp_continue` is indeed magic).

It would be more efficient to use `append accum $expect_out(0,string)`, but the way it is done isn't *wrong*.

Comment: it appends or it sets? because in the code, we used set, next time, accum will be rewroten!

Comment: @ratzip: Both. `set foo "${foo}bar"` *appends* `bar` to the variable `foo` by *setting* the variable `foo` to its current value plus `bar`.